# View from two tables with no key relations

Tags: sql-server

I have `category` table below :

```
id  min     max
1   0       1000
2   1001    20000
3   20001   1000000000
```

and `data` table below :

```
id  weight
1   1000
2   500
3   2000
4   5000
5   20000
6   200
7   100
8   25000
9   18000
10  26000
```

I want to make a view that shows the data belong to which category like this :

```
data.id category.id
1       1
2       1
3       2
4       1
5       2
6       1
7       1
8       3
9       2
10      3
```

If there is duplicate category meet the criteria, just show the lowest `category.id`.

### Update

Rules :

```
category.id = SELECT TOP(1) id FROM category WHERE @data.weight BETWEEN min AND max
```

Is that possible to do that just using view without stored procedure?

Comment: I can be definitely done by cross/outer apply. But I don't understand the rule, which assigns the "category.id" to "data.id".

Comment: What's the reason for "without join"? You are aware that join conditions can be arbitrary, and aren't limited strictly to equality, aren't you?

Comment: @TcKs : Rules added, thank you.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : I edit the tittle, I don't know the best tittle for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with a join, or with a correlated subquery, or using `apply` as TcKs suggested in the comments. Here are the join and correlated subquery versions of the queries:

```
declare @category table (id int not null,min int not null,max int not null)
insert into @category(id,min,max) values
(1,0    ,1000       ),
(2,1001 ,20000      ),
(3,20001,1000000000 )

declare @data table (id int not null,weight int not null)
insert into @data(id,weight) values
(1 ,1000  ),
(2 ,500   ),
(3 ,2000  ),
(4 ,5000  ),
(5 ,20000 ),
(6 ,200   ),
(7 ,100   ),
(8 ,25000 ),
(9 ,18000 ),
(10,26000 )

select d.id,MIN(c.id) as category_id
from @data d
    inner join
    @category c
        on
            d.weight between c.min and c.max
group by d.id

select d.id,(select MIN(c.id) from @category c
            where c.min <= d.weight and c.max >= d.weight) as category_id
from @data d
```

I'm using table variables just to simplify the script. The choice between `between` and explicit comparisons is also arbitrary and either could be used in either query. If the ranges were semi-open (inclusive min, exclusive max is fairly common) then the explicit comparison variant would be required.

Results:

```
id          category_id
----------- -----------
1           1
2           1
3           2
4           2
5           2
6           1
7           1
8           3
9           2
10          3
```